# How do you use the multi-line Console in Firebug?

Tags: firefox, console, firebug

The Firebug addon for Firefox supports a multiline Console, but how do you return values to show up in the Console's output? When I press "Run", all I see is a copy of my source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it. The last line of the multiline source code must return a value, to be outputted.

Eg.

```
var myVar = myFunction();
myVar;
```

Comment: Funny thing how I'm answering my own question, and in record time too!

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `console.log(obj);` or `console.log("hello world");`?